# About Solar's simulacrum

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, monsters, simulacrum

The simulacrum has less HD than the original creature, but to what extent does it retain the original creature's abilities? For example, How many spells and spell-like abilities does Solar's simulacrum have?

Answer (score 3):

### The rules do not say in detail

[Simulacrum](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/simulacrum.htm) says:

> It appears to be the same as the original, but it has only one-half of the real creature’s levels or Hit Dice (and the appropriate hit points, feats, skill ranks, and special abilities for a creature of that level or HD).

The [Solar](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Solar), is a monster, not a playable character class. Unfortunately, while you can determine exactly how many feats, skill ranks, and special abilities a character of a given level and race has, there is no such detailed, official guidance in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* or the *Monster Manual* for scaling monsters. That means, there are no official rules about how to construct a version of a solar that only has half as many hit dice, when it comes to assigning other features.

Of course, you can desconstruct what the formulas behind the monsters in the *Monster Manual*, might roughly look like, and there is some guidance on how advancing hit dice for a monster affects it. And there are [inofficial guides on how to modifify monsters](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?650844-A-3-5-DM-s-Guide-to-Using-and-Improving-Monsters). So you can try and triangulate what it likely might look like. But this, to a large extend, is up to you as the DM.

For example, the Solar is a 20th level divine spellcaster. It might be reasonable, if you half their hit dice, to also half the spellcasting level, to have spells like a 10th level divine caster. As an [outsider](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Outsider_Type), it would have a base attack bonus equal to its total hit dice, so that would be +11 instead of +22. It would have 8+int modifier skill points per hit die, plus 3 times that for the first hit die. The number of feats would also be halfed to four. And so on.

It is trickier for the special abilities like damage reduction, regeneration or spell-like abilities -- there you have to decide which of them are full-on innate to the solar, and which of them are due to the solar being fully evolved and in power. And of course, none of the original solar's equipment will be copied, so you will have to make do with lesser options, unless you happen to have a spare *+5 dancing greatsword* and a *+2 composite longbow* that creates arrows of slaying.